# Pass item data to a react modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a map that render few items and one of its line is below

```
<a onClick={()=> this.setState({"openDeleteModal":true)}>Delete</a>
```

Obviously I want to open a modal when user click the delete, but I have to pass a few things like the name of the item, id of the item to perform the deletion. How can I pass says the name to the modal?

I can bind the obj name to `a` like this
Delete

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 32):

When working on React applications, try not to think in terms of passing values to other components, but rather updating state that your components are exposed to. 
In your example, assuming your modal component is a child of the same component your list of `a` tags belongs to, you could set the values you are interested in exposing to the modal on the state, as well as updating the property that signals whether the modal is open or not. For example:

```
class Container extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props)
       this.state = {
          openDeleteModal: false,
          activeItemName: '', //state property to hold item name
          activeItemId: null, //state property to hold item id
       }
    }

    openModalWithItem(item) {
       this.setState({
          openDeleteModal: true,
          activeItemName: item.name,
          activeItemId: item.id
       })
    }

    render() {

    let buttonList = this.props.item.map( item => {
      return (<button onClick={() => this.openModalWithItem(item)}>{item.name}</button>
    });

    return (
     <div>
        {/* Example Modal Component */}
        <Modal isOpen={this.state.openDeleteModal}  
               itemId={this.state.activeItemId}
               itemName={this.state.activeItemName}/>
        { buttonList }
     </div>
    )
    }
}
```

Comment: Good stuff but I'm rendering a list and used a common modal. I don't see this is a good example in my case.

Comment: this is obviously a trivial example - but you could take this concept and apply it to your use case - in this example i am effectively rendering a list of buttons that all would trigger the common modal used in the render method.  depending on how big you app is - i would look at using Redux over state like this.

Comment: Excellent point! Thanks for steering my line of thinking. I come from a PHP world, and React really forces me to think outside the box. This is a much better approach than to what I was originally trying to do (passing data and returning a new component).

Answer (score 1):

Copying over my answer from [How to pass props to a modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53866458/how-to-pass-props-to-a-modal)

Similar scenario

```
constructor(props) {

    super(props)


    this.state = {
      isModalOpen: false,
      modalProduct: undefined,
    }
}

//****************************************************************************/

render() {

    return (
        <h4> Bag </h4>
        {this.state.isModalOpen & (
          <Modal 
            modalProduct={this.state.modalProduct}
            closeModal={() => this.setState({ isModalOpen: false, modalProduct: undefined})
            deleteProduct={ ... }
          />
        )

        {bag.products.map((product, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
            <div>{product.name}</div>
            <div>£{product.price}</div>
            <div>
            <span> Quantity:{product.quantity} </span>
            <button onClick={() => this.props.incrementQuantity(product, product.quantity += 1)}> + </button>
            <button onClick={() => this.decrementQuantity(product)}> - </button> // <----
            </div>
        </div>
        ))}
    )
}

//****************************************************************************/

decrementQuantity(product) {

    if(product.quantity === 1) {
        this.setState({ isModalOpen: true, modalProduct: product })
    } else {
        this.props.decrementQuantity(product)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: this is the form which has the button, and is a child component of some other component that passes the handleButtonAction method as props, and the button takes the input data and invokes this parent component method

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const data = e.target.elements.option.value.trim();
  if (!data) {
    this.setState(() => ({ error: 'Please type data' }));
  } else {
    this.props.handleButtonAction(data, date);
  }
} 

{this.state.error && <p>{this.state.error}</p>} 
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  <input type="text" name="option"/>
  <div>
    <button>Get data</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

The parent component:

```
handleButtonAction = (data) => {

  axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/someGetMethod/${data}`).then(response => {
        const resData = response.data;
        this.setState({
            openModal: true,
            status: response.status,
            data: resData
         });
    }).catch((error) => {
        if (error.message.toLowerCase() === 'network error') {              
          this.setStateWithError(-1, {});
        }
        else { // not found aka 404              
          this.setStateWithError(error.response.status, '', {currency, date: ddat});
        }
    });        
}
```