# How to pass props to a modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a shopping application where I map over some products and render them on screen. users can increase/decrease quantity. when the quantity gets to 1 and the user hits decrease, some middleware jumps in and asks if they are sure they want to remove it from the basket. if they click no then it will close the modal and leave it in the basket. if they click yes, it will close the modal and remove it from basket

how can I pass props to the modal to make sure I delete the correct product?

so far I have this. all the functionality is there and the ability to remove is there. I'm just not sure how to pass the particular product to the modal? the reason that the increment/decrement work is because they are part of the `map` that maps over each product. obviously when the modal loads, it is not part of the map. I have tried including it in the map but obviously this renders a modal for each product which isn't useful

```
<h4> Bag </h4>
<Modal />
{bag.products.map((product, index) => (
  <div key={index}>
    <div>{product.name}</div>
    <div>£{product.price}</div>
    <div>
      <span> Quantity:{product.quantity} </span>
      <button onClick={() => this.props.incrementQuantity(product, product.quantity += 1)}> + </button>
      <button onClick={() => this.props.decrementQuantity(product)}> - </button>
    </div>
  </div>
))}
```

any ideas?

Comment: Linked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335452/pass-item-data-to-a-react-modal

Comment: Linked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48292007/passing-prop-to-modal-react-native

Comment: If you're using some Modal script, i'm sure it has information in its repo on how to do it. if you're using your own, then you can use [React Portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) and then passing props becomes easier

Comment: @vsync so essentially it wants me to change some state so that something like "editableProductId" gets populated and then I just pass that back to the modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced a similar scenario recently. I managed it using redux/global state as I had to keep track of many modals. Similar approach with local state

```
//****************************************************************************/

constructor(props) {

    super(props)


    this.state = {
      isModalOpen: false,
      modalProduct: undefined,
    }
}

//****************************************************************************/

render() {

    return (
        <h4> Bag </h4>
        {this.state.isModalOpen & (
          <Modal 
            modalProduct={this.state.modalProduct}
            closeModal={() => this.setState({ isModalOpen: false, modalProduct: undefined})
            deleteProduct={ ... }
          />
        )

        {bag.products.map((product, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
            <div>{product.name}</div>
            <div>£{product.price}</div>
            <div>
            <span> Quantity:{product.quantity} </span>
            <button onClick={() => this.props.incrementQuantity(product, product.quantity += 1)}> + </button>
            <button onClick={() => this.decrementQuantity(product)}> - </button> // <----
            </div>
        </div>
        ))}
    )
}

//****************************************************************************/

decrementQuantity(product) {

    if(product.quantity === 1) {
        this.setState({ isModalOpen: true, modalProduct: product })
    } else {
        this.props.decrementQuantity(product)
    }
}
```